# How do I access local PDF files in my Chrome Extension app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extension, jspdf

Google Chrome allows you to preview local PDF files in the browser like pictured below:

[image]

I am working on an extension that takes whatever PDF is in the browser preview and opens it in my custom editor/markup tool.

I have been successful in loading PDFs from remote URLs because I can just send the remote URL to my server, download it there, and open the PDF in my app using PDFjs.

**How can I accomplish the same functionality for local PDF files?**

I have looked into possibly using javascript to create a `File` object from local PDF files but Chrome doesn't allow access to the local file system.

I am hoping to accomplish this functionality by the user just clicking my extension icon, similar to the popular extension, Kami.

Comment: You can also use [showOpenFilePicker](https://web.dev/file-system-access/) API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add permissions to your extension:

```
"permissions": ["file://*/*"]
```

to ensure that you have permissions for local files, use:

```
chrome.extension.isAllowedFileSchemeAccess
```

P.S. have a good day and do not use upwork for these type of questions :-D

Comment: it didn't work in manifest version 3